# iOS: ContainerView -- Externally calling prepareForSegue in childController

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue, container-view

In the following setup, `Button 1` calls `First VC` and `Button 2` calls `Second VC`

[image]

Currently, I use the following code to call `SecondVC` by tapping `Button 2`.

MainVC.m

```
@implementation MainVC()
....

UINavigationController *navController = [self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
SecondVC *secondVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second"];
[navController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
```

The code above displays `SecondVC` just fine.  However, in the `First VC` there are statements that need be executed before "Second VC" is presented, that are being skipped!

I execute these statements in `First VC` inside `-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`.  When the `Next` Button is tapped in the `First VC`, all the statements execute because it triggers `prepareForSegue` before presenting `SecondVC`. This step is skipped when the code above is used.

Extra Info:
**A)** Though a `Navigation Controller`, `Main VC` in my app does not show the navigation bar in my app.  I believe this would be against HIG to display two navigation bars on an iPhone.  I show it here to identify Main VC.
**B)** There are textFields in FirstVC that User fills out. If I just copy the code, will it read and save the data from textFields.text?

Question:  How can I call `prepareForSegue` from `First VC` when `Button 2` is tapped in `MainVC`? or is there another approach to this?

Comment: Is there anything in your design that prevents you from just copying the code from `prepareForSegue` into the method called when `Button 2` is pressed?

Comment: There are textFields in FirstVC that User fills out.  If I just copy the code, will it read and save the data from textFields.text?  Thanks.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. You'd need to access the data from MainVC and copy it to SecondVC. See my new answer for details.

Comment: Have you tried by connecting pushing the  view controller Second via Xib by establish the segue action in xib?>

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[self childViewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
UIViewController *vc = [navController topViewController]
if ([vc isKindOfClass:[FirstVC class]]) {
    FirstVC *firstVC = (FirstVC *)vc;
    SecondVC *secondVC = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second"];
    // Copy and read data from [[firstVC textField] text] to secondVC.
    [navController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: What does an NSLog(@"FirstVC: %@", firstVC) result in?